# How can I make a deploy of my flutter application to a VDS server

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, dart, deployment

I've written my application and now I want it to work whether my pc is running or not.(I've only had experience with Firebase before). I rented a vds server and database on mongoDB. I was able to connect to the remote database and make some records. But I don't quite understand how to upload the project to the server. As I understand, I need to download the project from my GitHub, install all dependencies, then in the functions where I make requests change localhost to public ip address, or private? (instead of http://localhost:3000/fetchPosts make for example http://:3000/fetchPosts).

Then go to the project and do a flutter run, did I get it right? Or maybe I missed something?

Stack
Dart
Node.js and express
Mongo DB